# Can you use 2 Minecraft mods simultaneously?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I was wondering if you could simultaneously load 2 mods such as a hacked client like Nodus, and TMI? I have tried to just place both jar files but that did not work.

Comment: We do not help with piracy.  Since Nodus is a hacked client, we will not help you get it working with anything.

Comment: Nodus requires a minecraft account so it's not piracy. It's basically just a mod that includes "utilities" such as Xray, chatspamming, etc. that can make other people's lives miserable

Comment: @JoethePerson Can you point at some info about that?  I Google Nodus, all I get is, "hacked client".  That doesn't spell legit to me.

Comment: Unless they've changed it, when I used it, a minecraft log-in was requires, so they weren't giving the game for free or anything. Technically all mods are "hacking" minecraft because they involve decompiling the sources and redistributing a modified version

Comment: I said Nodus just so people would have a sence of what i am talking about, since it is one of the most popular Hacked Clients. I was just wondering if mods could co-exist

Comment: @JoethePerson hacked client, as far as gaming goes, typically means pirated game, hence the VTC twitch both Frank and I had.

Comment: @MBraedley Uh no. Just, because you use an alternate launcher for a game doesn't mean the game is necessarily circumventing DRM, or at least that's not the sole purpose normally. Examples: Nexus (Fallout series, TES series, and others), MagicLauncher (Minecraft), FOM (Fallout), and various others.

Comment: @KernelPanic more famously Tekkit and Feed the Beast for Minecraft

Comment: I think this meta post applies here as well. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7553/51318

Comment: @KernelPanic using a term like "alternative launcher" is vastly better than "hacked client".  Yes, in the past, a hacked client could be used for applying mods, but more often than not, it was used to play a pirated game.

Answer (score 0):

Mods won't work together if they modify the same files. TMI shares files with Nodus, so you won't be able to run both at the same time